# SQL Query : Obtaining Rows where Columns A in Table A = Column A in Table B

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am probably being completely thick here.

I have a tables with a list of reason codes in, the 'access' to these reasons is limited by whether or not columns have 1 or 0 in.

```
ID | Category | Reason | Brand1 | Brand2 | Brand3
1  |  Test    |  That  |   1    |    1   |    0
2  |  Test2   |  This  |   0    |    1   |    0
3  |  Test3   |  Mine  |   0    |    0   |    1
```

The user table

```
Username | Brand1 | Brand2 | Brand3
  User1  |    1   |   1    |    0
```

Basically User1 should only be able to see the reasons whereby they have a 1 in the Users Table in the Brand Columns they have a 1 in the Brand column in the Reasons Table.

User1 should only be able to see the reason ID 1 & 2 because they have a 1 in Brand1 and 1 in Brand2 in the User Table.

I only wish to return the rows from the Reasons Table, whereby the User in the Users Table has a match 1 in the corresponding 'Brand' column.

i.e.

User 1 should return

```
ID | Category | Reason | Brand1 | Brand2 | Brand3
1  |  Test    |  That  |   1    |    1   |    0
2  |  Test2   |  This  |   0    |    1   |    0
```

How would I get this in SQL, I tried writing it with OR's in the WHERE statement but it was always returning every row. There are 7 Brand columns in total.

I think I'm overlooking something simple here from over complicating the matter.

Cheers

Comment: Please add the desired result based on your sample data.

Comment: Also post your  statement. Even If you simply compared each column for equality (eg `WHERE A.Brand1=B.Brand1 OR A.Brand2=B.Brand2`),  #3 shouldn't appear

Comment: How's SQL looks like?

Comment: @JohnOdom typo sorry chap.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have no way of 'joining' the 2 tables together as they have nothing in common other than the 'Brand' columns but I can't join them otherwise it defeats the object of the WHERE statement surely?

Comment: @Lynchie no, in fact all 3 solutions use joins. A join is made based on *any* expression, not just equality between columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you post your SQL then I could get something closer.

Otherwise:

```
SELECT *
FROM        Reasons AS R
INNER JOIN  UserTable AS U
    ON      (U.Brand1 = 1 AND U.Brand1 = R.Brand1)
        OR  (U.Brand2 = 1 AND U.Brand2 = R.Brand2)
        OR  (U.Brand3 = 1 AND U.Brand3 = R.Brand3);
```

This will get only the rows where the user has a brand that the reason also has.  Technically you could change the `U.Brand# = R.Brand#` to just `R.Brand# = 1`, but that might be hard for others to read later.

```
SELECT *
FROM        Reasons AS R
INNER JOIN  UserTable AS U
    ON      (U.Brand1 = 1 AND R.Brand1 = 1)
        OR  (U.Brand2 = 1 AND R.Brand2 = 1)
        OR  (U.Brand3 = 1 AND R.Brand3 = 1);
```

This would probably be faster than the second query, but not enough to notice in most situations.

Answer (score 2):

If I Understood Correctly try below script

```
SELECT t.ID , t.Category , t.Reason , t.Brand1 , t.Brand2 , t.Brand3
FROM TableName t,UserTable U
WHERE (t.Brand1 =U.Brand1 AND t.Brand1 = 1 ) OR 
      (t.Brand2 = U.Brand2 AND t.Brand2 = 1 ) OR
      (t.Brand3 =U.Brand3 AND t.Brand3 = 1 )
```

Comment: Hi jaydipJ, close but it returns all the rows whereby 0 exists as well, I only want the rows where 1 exists.

Comment: @Lynchie Good Catch Updated Ans

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
     rt.*
FROM ReasonTable AS rt
INNER JOIN UserTable AS ut ON (rt.Id = 1 AND ut.Brand1 = 1)
OR (rt.Id = 2 AND ut.Brand2 = 1) OR (rt.Id = 3 AND ut.Brand2 = 1)
WHERE ut.UserId = @userId
```